# Why is the primeng dropdown list no firing?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Disclaimer, I am very new to primeng...

I have the following component

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { TimeRangesService } from './time.range.service';

@Component({
               moduleId   : module.id,
               selector: 'time-range',
               templateUrl: './time.range.component.html',
           })

export class TimeRangesControl  implements OnInit {
    timeRanges: any[];
    selectedTimeRange: any;
    constructor(private timeRangeService: TimeRangesService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.timeRangeService.get().then(res => this.timeRanges = res);
    }

    onChange($event) {
        console.log('event');
    }
}
```

I never get the onChange function called.
In my html file, I say:

```
<div class="content-section implementation">
<p-dropdown
        [style]="{'width': '40%', 'height': '30px'}"
        onChange="onChange"
        [options]="timeRanges"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedTimeRange"
        placeholder="Select a time range"></p-dropdown>
<p>Selected Time Range: {{selectedTimeRange ? selectedTimeRange.name : 'none'}}</p>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes:

html:

`(onChange)="onChange($event)"`

component.ts:

```
onChange(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem.